# Which admin module use for rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, admin, activeadmin, rails-admin

I want add to my rails application admin module, but I don't know which chose. I saw that most popular is `activeadmin` and `rails_admin`. I need some admin in which I can create my pages with other handlers. Can this admin modules help me create admin panel or not? Maybe I can use something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both, `active_admin` and `rails_admin` provide convenient ways to access and manage your database from a GUI interface.  How you present that data is totally upto you.  If by admin panel, you mean an admin dashboard like this, neither of them does that: [image]

Admin dashboards are very application specific and depends on what type of data you want to display.  active_admin and rails_admin will help you get data from your application but it's then upto you to display that data in whatever format/interface you want.

Comment: I use flask-admin and in this python module for framework flask, you can create your own HTML pages with different handlers. Can I do in one of this modules?

Comment: Yes, you will be able to customize it with your own html